# Print a chart from Google Sheets horizontally

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing, google-cloud-print

**I need to find ways of printing a chart as pdf/image/sheet horizontally**.

I print automatically with code.

Now I am printing a pdf created out of a Spreadsheet tab but it always prints vertically despite options settings.

It saves beautiful horizontal pdfs on Drive but then prints them vertically.

As I print statistics I need it to be horizontally.

Here's my code with options:

```js
  var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };  
  
  //spreadsheet id
  var ssID = ss.getId()
  
  //sheet id
  var sID = ss.getSheetByName("Print").getSheetId();
   
  //creating pdf  
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?gid="+sID+"&portrait=false&size=letter&fitw=true&format=pdf",requestData).getBlob();  
  
  //folder to created pdf in
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RseEezmGT2gSBS9rgdV0E2ggRD5O6dyu")
 
  //creating pdf in this folder with given name
  var file = folder.createFile(pdf).setName("Chart")
  
  var docID = file.getId()

  var printerID = "02f4280c-9e83-da7d-d5ff-ca0f25ca03e3"
  var docName = "Chart"

  //starts printing
  printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName)
```

And

```js
function printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName) {
  
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR",
        vendor_id: "Color"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      }
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid" : printerID,
    "title"     : docName,
    "content"   : DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getBlob(),  
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "ticket"    : JSON.stringify(ticket)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });
```

So I am using here an option `portrait=false` to print as a landscape. Doesn't work.

Appreciate any solutions for horizontal printing.

Comment: Error might also have something to do `printGoogleDocument` function. Provide that code too.

Comment: @TheMaster updated the post with this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try including `page_orientation` in the ticket:

```
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR",
        vendor_id: "Color"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
      page_orientation: { //Added
        type:1//or type:"LANDSCAPE"
      }
    }
  };
```

#### References:

- [PageOrientationTicket](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#PageOrientationTicketItem)
- [PageOrientationEnum](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#PageOrientation)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work like this. You're sure the format is correct?

Comment: I've tried png image instead of pdf and it prints image horizontally but on vertical page (the printer default is landscape). If someone help handle png that would help to. Either pdf or png.

Comment: @kiki Have you also tried `type:"LANDSCAPE"`? You may also try setting `dpi` and `fit_to_page` options. If those don't work, Can you try cloud printing from your mobile? If so, Were you able to achieve the result you're looking for?

Comment: fit_to_page: { type: 1} worked. Thank you! It printed horizontal chart on a horizontal page.

Comment: but the space around the chart is too big)) I tried to use margins: { type: "BORDERLESS" or margins: { type: 0 } and it's an error. Do you know how to put it right?

Comment: @kik Does the pdf have margins? Try `margins:{top_microns:1,left_microns:0}`

Comment: I print as a png image not pdf. I'll try it. I wanna fill the chart more to edges. Otherwise your answer is helpful and you can submit it as a separate correct answer.

Comment: margins:{top_microns:1,left_microns:0} didn't worked. It says "Error Code: 433.0 Invalid print ticket.".

Comment: @kiki Try `margins:{top_microns:1,left_microns:1,bottom_microns:1,right_microns:1}` OR `margins:{type:0,top_microns:1,left_microns:1,bottom_microns:1,right_microns:1}`